# Paperclip test failing

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, paperclip

I am using the paperclip gem to upload images.

I have a test that looks like this;

```
describe Person do
  it { should have_attached_file(:image_one) }
end
```

and in my models I have the following code

```
class Person < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :first_name, :last_name, :gender, :story, :image_one
  has_attached_file :image_one
end
```

and the test is still failing.

I also have the following in my spec_helper file

```
require 'paperclip/matchers'
config.include Paperclip::Shoulda::Matchers
```

Is there anything I am doing incorrectly?

Comment: Do you have `config.include Paperclip::Shoulda::Matchers` inside of the configuration block?

Comment: yes it is in the block

Comment: What error are you getting? What version of Rails are you using?

Comment: FWIW, the class definition and spec "pass" in Rails 4 without the `attr_accessible` line, which is now deprecated.

Comment: am using rails-3.2.13 and the test is failing with the following message.                                                              "Failure/Error: it { should have_attached_file(:image_one) }
Should have an attachment named image_one"

Answer (score 1):

For me it was test database scheme out of sync and `rake db:test:load` fixed the issue.